# Dynamic Programming for String Matching in JAVA

Tags: java, string, dynamic-programming

I wish to search for a sequence within a source string however, the sequence might have allowed insertions. For example, the sequence: AG**GC would allow up to two insertions and it would match either AGGC or AGTGC or AGTTGC, etc.

I have tried a dynamic programming approach in Java but can't seem to get it to work for a specified number of *. The program does not differentiate between one * and two *. So if I put a * it allows any number of insertions.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to make the * specify only one character?

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class GFG{      

// Function that matches input str with 
// given wildcard pattern 
static boolean strmatch(String str, String pattern, 
                             int n, int m) 
{ 
    // empty pattern can only match with 
    // empty string 
    if (m == 0) 
        return (n == 0); 

    // lookup table for storing results of 
    // subproblems 
    boolean[][] lookup = new boolean[n + 1][m + 1]; 

    // initailze lookup table to false 
    for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) 
        Arrays.fill(lookup[i], false); 


    // empty pattern can match with empty string 
    lookup[0][0] = true; 

    // Only '*' can match with empty string 
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) 
        if (pattern.charAt(j - 1) == '*') 
            lookup[0][j] = lookup[0][j - 1]; 

    // fill the table in bottom-up fashion 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) 
        { 
            // Two cases if we see a '*' 
            // a) We ignore '*'' character and move 
            //    to next  character in the pattern, 
            //     i.e., '*' indicates an empty sequence. 
            // b) '*' character matches with ith 
            //     character in input 
            if (pattern.charAt(j - 1) == '*') 
                lookup[i][j] = lookup[i][j - 1] || 
                               lookup[i - 1][j]; 

            // Current characters are considered as 
            // matching in two cases 
            // (a) current character of pattern is '?' 
            // (b) characters actually match 
            else if (pattern.charAt(j - 1) == '?' || 
                str.charAt(i - 1) == pattern.charAt(j - 1)) 
                lookup[i][j] = lookup[i - 1][j - 1]; 

            // If characters don't match 
            else lookup[i][j] = false; 
        } 
    } 

    return lookup[n][m]; 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    String str = "baabab"; 
    String pattern = "ba**********ab"; 
    // String pattern = "ba*****ab"; 
    // String pattern = "ba*ab"; 
    // String pattern = "a*ab"; 
    // String pattern = "a*****ab"; 
    // String pattern = "*a*****ab"; 
    // String pattern = "ba*ab****"; 
    // String pattern = "****"; 
    // String pattern = "*"; 
    // String pattern = "aa?ab"; 
    // String pattern = "b*b"; 
    // String pattern = "a*a"; 
    // String pattern = "baaabab"; 
    // String pattern = "?baaabab"; 
    // String pattern = "*baaaba*"; 

    if (strmatch(str, pattern, str.length(), 
                         pattern.length())) 
        System.out.println("YES"); 
    else
        System.out.println("No"); 

} 
}
```

Comment: why `AGTC` = think you need to explain your logic a bit more.  Also please what code you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic programming approach in Java"? Have you tried using regex?

Comment: Regex does not allow insertions (or it will take too long).

Comment: Sorry about that I just fixed it

Comment: You need to specify if a  * can represent 0 or 1 character or 2 characters or more? It seems from your example that a * can represent 0 or 1 character. Is it?

Comment: Yeah, that the problem I am running into.

Comment: @SomeDude, do you have suggestions on how to specify the number of characters?

Comment: This is something that needs to be specified in the problem description.

Comment: Added it to the description